# Issue with xml file containing utf-16 encoding?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I am working with some xml files which I want to parse with python. In order to do so, I am trying one of the modules `import lxml.etree as etree` or `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`, but with both I have issues.
Using `lxml.etree` code:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-16')
tree = etree.parse(xml_file, parser)
```

gives the following error on parse:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Using the module `xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-16")
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
```

gives the following error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect: line 1, column 30
```

I am working with very complex files, but it is reproducible on the small one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<OrderMessage version="9.0" type="Add"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://schemas.sthg.com/sthg/sthg/2019/03">
<Example>test</Example>
</OrderMessage>
```

Also what I sometimes observed that for some files parsing is ok, but tags are completely messed up.
Can you help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the following code can solve your problem. You try, if it works, we can communicate the next needs.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

# html = utils.getFileContent(xml_file,encoding="utf-16") # Replace with your real XML file
html = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<OrderMessage version="9.0" type="Add"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://schemas.sthg.com/sthg/sthg/2019/03">
<Example>test</Example>
</OrderMessage>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.Example.text)
```

Result:

```
test
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked on simplified example, but not on big one. But this big one was modified which caused the issue. So far it is working fine, but will check against more files.